# Crear una base de datos desde cero al ejecutar proyecto Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring, jpa

¿Es posible crear una base de datos MySQL desde cero al ejecutar un proyecto de Spring Boot?

En todos los ejemplos que he visto, la base de datos ya está creada, y la propiedad `jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` afecta a las tablas, no a la base de datos en sí.
Yo lo he intentado incluyendo la sentencia `CREATE SCHEMA` en el archivo `schema.sql`, que supuestamente se ejecuta al iniciar, el cual quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS libreria_v04b;
USE libreria_v04b;
```

Y este es el archivo `application.yml`:

```
spring: 
  datasource: 
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/libreria_v04b?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=Europe/Madrid&characterEncoding=UTF-8
    username: root
    password: root
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver 
  sql:
    init: 
      mode: always
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false 
server:
  error:
    whitelabel:
      enabled: false
```

Sin embargo, al ejecutar aparece el siguiente error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'libreria_v04b'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:446) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:239) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:188) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:160) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:118) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:52) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:87) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applyScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:108) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applySchemaScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:98) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.initializeDatabase(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:76) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1158) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at com.LibreriaMV1704.LibreriaMv1704Application.main(LibreriaMv1704Application.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
```

Gracias.